# Symfony 3.4 project. How do I add a search functionality?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I am developing a Symfony 3.4 project. It is composed by a couple of bundles: a very simple blog (blogs/posts/comments entities), web pages (pages/contents) and something to show timelines (timelines/events). Now I want to add a search button and a way to let a user to query underlying data, from all those entities.

Let me explain myself with a very simple minded scenario. User searches 'goofy' and say 'goofy' occurs within a few post records (within a 'message' and 'title' field), a couple of event records ('description' field) and several content records (...). I need to return a list of links to the different views, say to blog/post/1/show, ..., page/content/27/show,...,  timeline/event/19/show, ... .

I think I could do that piecemeal by plain php+sql . Question is, is there something ready to go, such that I just need to configure it?

Otherwise, should I rather index my data?

To index data, I see  [Symfony](https://symfony.com/blog/the-new-symfony-documentation-search-engine) suggests Algolia, but it seems to heavy a solution for my simple project. (Also, I understand that Algolia is not something that I may run  my server, does it?)

I see  [FOSElasticaBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle) (and [Elastica](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch)) too, but I am not sure whether it is still being updated. Also, it seems it had some  [security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639893/elasticsearch-index-deleted).

Comment: Use a simple form

Comment: @Albeis, yes, I edited to explain myself better.

Comment: Algolia has a free option, I believe, up to some extent, which is perfect for small, project. However, my advice is, go with your own simple search because you probably won't be having a huge amount of data and thus no need to index it outside. When you get comfortable with your project and decide to extend it a bit, then try out Algolia, it's fairly easy to implement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For such a simple project without many search dimensions and without any specific requirements, I would just use a plain Symfony form and directly query the DB

A full search/indexing service will be a complete overkill. 
Unless of course you want to use the project as a chance to learn those technologies.

---

Edit:

A simple approach is to do a join of all the tables that you wish to query, do a LIKE '%myfilter%' on all the text fields that you wish to check, retrieve the id of the entity, pass them to twig and then in a loop get the path of the entity's view controller passing the id parameter to it.
That should work very nicely if your schema is simple and your have relatively few records. 
In such a case I would stick to LIKE and avoid using full text indexes (..WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST...) because mysql is very slow at combining such indexes with other ones on complex queries with joins.

A slightly more elaborate approach would be to use a listener or something on doctrine to maintain a serialized full text representation of each entity on a separate single table which you can then query directly, avoiding the possibly complex joins and their overhead. You can also query a full text index more safely in such a case.

This might also open the way to more easy switch to a different indexer/search engine (when the time comes), since you have already done some work to decouple your search/indexing from the structure of your actual model.

Comment: yes, most likely. See edit. Happy if you elaborate a little about how 'directly query'.

Comment: I added some more detailed simple approaches. Check my edit above. Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: @ Dimitris thks so much. I'll try the serialized full text representation approach, my new homework,  and be back. Do you know any good tutorial?

Comment: This should be straight forward. Your biggest challenge will be to decide on how to serialize your entities (probably json). Check symfony and jms serializer tutorials. I would then create events (new/update/delete) and listeners, and dispatch them every time a change is made on your entity. Avoid using doctrine lifecycle events and listeners. They do not work nicely with flushes in them.
And then you should use native sql to do the search. That way you can do full text queries on mysql. Doctrine does not support them since they are vendor specific
Please post back what you have chosen:)

Comment: By the way, if you find yourself trying to add other search dimensions like type, brand, model, etc, you might want to consider jumping to postgresql and use jsonb queries. They will be infinitely faster and simpler to code

Comment: @ Dimitris Hi, need help on the serialize part. I try  jms. Within one of my controller I try:   `$serializer = \JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
 $serializer->serialize($myEntity, 'json');
        $eventDispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');
  $eventDispatcher->dispatch(
        'basic.event.name', new BasicEvent()
        )->eventdump($serializer);`  (eventdump() just dump!)
Then what?  I understand you suggest to save my data in a new table. Do you mean I need to create a new Entity class? and what I am supposed to save therein?  Do I need to deserialize?

Comment: You need a variable to hold your serialized entity. When you do $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json') you basically get a string representation of your entity. And then you can either save it in a new "search" table using a new entity, or in a column on your main entity table. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: var_dump(serialized entity `$jsonContent`) is a huge amount of extra data. How do I single out what I wish/need? More general, if I have several entities (and so many more CRUD controllers), do I need to dispatch/listen to each of them from within every single action? Is there a way to do it somehow in a centralized way?

Comment: To cherrypick data you can choose either native sql or query builder with partial entities. I would probably use native sql. To handle it centrally, I would create a custom event that I would dispatch every time one of the entities is altered (passing it the id of the central entity). And then handle the search table update on a listener that gets the id of the central entity from the event and does the actual join/serialize/store of the new data.

Comment: Oh and a nice way to centrally trigger the indexing without manually dispatching it on every controller, you can hook into onFlush event of Doctrine, check the unit of work if it contains any entities that interest you, and trigger your custom event then. Just be careful not to flush yourself. And there might be a slight overhead by the listener on all your flushes. Check this thread for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289918/creating-an-entity-while-updating-another/51290179#51290179