# Creating an entity while updating another

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have one question I don't seem to find an answer to.

I have my User entity with a "Status" field.

What I want to do is store in another table "StatusEvent" a new line each time the status of a user is changed to keep track of the history of statuses of my users.

I tried to work with the PreUpdate method but it doesn't allow the creation of new Entities in this step.

I was maybe thinking that it might be possible with other events (onFlush maybe?) but these do not have the methods of the LifecycleEventArgs from PreUpdate (which allows to know if a field has been changed).

Anyone has already came across a same pattern or has an idea on how I could implement it?

Thanks by advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution by @Dimitris would work, but requires you to dispatch the event manually.

I would use the `onFlush` method like you mentioned. (If you are writing a library, you are better off with the custom event)

You can use UnitOfWork to get the change sets.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
{
    $em = $event->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        $this->newEntities[] = $entity;

        if ($entity instanceof User) {
            $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

            // if the $changeSet contains the status, log the change
            $log = new Log();

            $em->persist($log);
            $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata(Log::class), $log);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        // same here, create a private method to avoid duplication
    }
}
```

The trade off of this listener is it will only log things on flush.
If your entity changes state multiple times before flush, only the last state will be logged. Eg state1 -> 2 -> 3 will only be logged as state1 -> 3

If you plan on creating a complex status field with many states and transitions have a look at the workflow component and use the listeners from there. It is a bit more work, but well worth it.

Comment: Nice. Just remember to not flush inside the listener or you will end up in an infinite loop. It's easy to do it by simple muscle memory. If I may, one thing I hate about the lifecycle events of doctrine is that you need knowledge of how/when they are fired and how the entity manager works internally. I almost always go for a custom event because the code is far easier to follow, even for newbies. $workflows++ :)

Comment: I'm going to check this out ! I didn't know that I could access the actual ChangeSet on the onFlush. I'll come back and tell you if it's working. I might mix both solutions and fire a custom event to not mess too much with the onFlush and get the StatusEvent creation logic in its own file :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice case to use a custom event and listener.

Create a class UserEvents to hold a constant with the event name like

```
class UserEvents
{
    const STATUS_CHANGED = 'user.status.changed';
}
```

Create a UserStatusChangedEvent that extends Event and takes the user as a parameter.

```
class UserChangedEvent extends Event
{
    private $user;
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And then create and register a listener to capture/handle that event and create the entry that you need using the data from the user object that was passed in the event when it was dispatched.

```
class UserListener
{
    public function onStatusChanged(UserChangedEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();
        //TODO: Create your new status change entry. If you need the entity manager, just inject it in the constructor, like with any other service
    }
}
```

You then need to register you listener as a service and tag it

```
AppBundle\Event\Listener\UserListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: user.status.changed, method: onStatusChanged }
```

And now all you have to do is dispatch a new instance of the event every time the status changes, passing it the user that you just persisted.

```
$eventDispatcher->dispatch(
    UserEvents::STATUS_CHANGED,
    $user
);
```

Edit: To defend the manual dispatching of the custom event VS the automated dispatch of onFlush, the custom event code is far easier to read even from a newbie that has no knowledge of how/when doctrine lifecycle events are triggered or how the entity manager works internally. The cherry at the top is that the dispatching works as a nice reminder that you have a listener there, which will be useful when you revisit your code in a few months.

Comment: I thought about this solution, and in general my code is mainly built around firing events (it helps to get the actual logic well organised) but in this part I am using Sonata Admin and I didn't find an easy enough way to plug myself in and fire a custom event (other than overriding the full Sonata CRUD controller which seems a bit excessive)

Comment: I have no significant experience with Sonata, but they have their own events that you can use: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/events.html#persistenceevent

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But I might try a mix of your solution and Padam's one by firing a custom event from the onFlush :)

Answer (score 0):

So what I did following the advice of both Dimitris and Padam67.

- Define a DoctrineListener that listens on the onFlush event and register it
- Dispatch a custom event in the DoctrineListener
- Define an EventSubscriber listening on my custom event
- Define a handler to manage the logic
- Call the handler from the EventSubscriber

I know it makes a lot of files, but I like to separate everything as much as possible for a cleaner and simpler code to read :)

### Define a DoctrineListener that listens on the onFlush event:

`config/services.yaml`

```
App\EventListener\Doctrine\DoctrineListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

`App\EventListener\Doctrine\DoctrineListener.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener\Doctrine;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork;
use App\Event\TalentStatusChangedEvent;
use App\Entity\Talent;
use App\Event\Constants\TalentEvents;

class DoctrineListener
{
    private $logger;
    private $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $event)
    {
        $entityManager = $event->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Talent) {
                $this->createTalentStatusChangedEvent($entity, $uow);
            }
        }

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Talent) {
                $this->createTalentStatusChangedEvent($entity, $uow);
            }
        }
    }

    private function createTalentStatusChangedEvent(Talent $entity, UnitOfWork $uow)
    {
        $this->logger->info(self::class . ' - talentStatusChanged: ' . $entity . ' - start');
        $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
        if (array_key_exists('status', $changeSet)) {
            $talentStatusChangedEvent = new TalentStatusChangedEvent($entity, new \DateTime());
            $this->dispatcher->dispatch(TalentEvents::STATUS_CHANGED, $talentStatusChangedEvent);
            $this->logger->info(self::class . ' - talentStatusChanged: ' . $entity . ' - success');
        } else {
            $this->logger->info(self::class . ' - talentStatusChanged: ' . $entity . ' - fail');
        }

    }
}
```

### Define a TalentStatusChangedEvent

`App\Event\TalentStatusChangedEvent.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use App\Entity\Talent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class TalentStatusChangedEvent extends Event
{
    private $talent;
    private $statusChangedDate;

    public function __construct(Talent $talent, \DateTime $date)
    {
        $this->talent = $talent;
        $this->statusChangedDate = $date;
    }

    public function getTalent()
    {
        return $this->talent;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->talent->getStatus();
    }

    public function getStatusChangedDate()
    {
        return $this->statusChangedDate;
    }
}
```

### Define an EventSubscriber for my event (defined a separate file containing all my events per type)

`App\EventListener\Admin\User\TalentSubscriber.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener\Admin\User;

use App\Domain\User\StatusChanged\StatusChangedHandler;
use App\Entity\Talent;
use App\Event\Constants\TalentEvents;
use App\Event\TalentStatusChangedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class TalentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $statusChangedHandler;

    public function __construct(
        StatusChangedHandler $statusChangedHandler
    ) {
        $this->statusChangedHandler = $statusChangedHandler;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            TalentEvents::STATUS_CHANGED => 'statusChanged',
        );
    }

    public function statusChanged(TalentStatusChangedEvent $event) {
        $this->statusChangedHandler->handle($event);
    }
}
```

### Define a handler to actually manage the creation of the linked entity

`App\Domain\User\StatusChanged.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Domain\User\StatusChanged;

use App\Entity\Talent;
use App\Entity\TalentStatusEvent;
use App\Event\TalentStatusChangedEvent;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class StatusChangedHandler
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function handle(TalentStatusChangedEvent $event)
    {
        $this->logger->info(self::class . ' - Talent ' . $event->getTalent() . ' - start');
        $talentStatusEvent = new TalentStatusEvent();
        $talentStatusEvent->setTalent($event->getTalent());
        $talentStatusEvent->setStatus($event->getStatus());
        $this->entityManager->persist($talentStatusEvent);
        // Calling ComputeChangeSet and not flush because we are during the onFlush cycle
        $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet(
            $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata(TalentStatusEvent::class),
            $talentStatusEvent
        );
        $this->logger->info(self::class . ' - Talent ' . $event->getTalent() . ' - success');
    }
}
```